# Inverting a symbolic matrix with Julia

Tags: julia

I am using the Symbolics.jl package and trying to invert a matrix. However, the output is giving 'true' instead of 1. Here is the code:

```
using Symbolics

@variables x

 mat=[x 0 0

       0 x 0

       0 0 x]
```

And the result I get is

```
 inv(mat)= [true / x   0      0

               0   true / x    0

               0     0       true / x]
```

Any thought on why this is happening?

Comment: That looks like the correct inverse. What's the issue?

Answer (score 6):

First of, this is not wrong as  `inv(mat) * mat` will still give you the identity matrix. the problem is that the identity matrix in `Num` (the data type representing `Symbolic.jl`'s variable is the diagonal matrix with `true` in its diagonal. This can be checked by looking at
`Matrix{Num}(I, 3, 3)`.

The inverse is calculated by solving the system `AX = I` and the `true` is created when the dense identity matrix is created.

This is due to the definition of `I`, namely `const I = UniformScaling(true)`. My guess (and correct me if i'm wrong) is that this is for maximum compatibility. Normally this gets translated to a 1 in integer types but `Num` is an exception.